# What is storage_location in terms of SSTORE?

Tags: gas

I notice the [gas table](https://ethgastable.info/) states:

> ((value != 0) && (storage_location == 0)) ? 20000 : 5000

for `SSTORE`. What does it mean by `storage_location`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ((value != 0) && (storage_location == 0)) ? 20000 : 5000

This is basically saying that it costs 20,000 gas to set any given storage location - i.e. storage slot - from 0 to `value`, and 5,000 gas to change its value thereafter.

So `storage_location` in the above will mean whichever slot in the storage we are considering.

e.g. If we are considering slot number 5 in storage, then in the above pseudo-code `storage_location` will be set to 5, and we are checking whether its current value is 0.

---

Appendix G in the [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) puts it thusly:

```
Gsset   20000  Paid for an SSTORE operation when the storage value is set to non-zero from zero.
Gsreset 5000   Paid for an SSTORE operation when the storage value’s zeroness remains unchanged or
is set to zero
```

Comment: So, the gas cost of `update` operation is 5000, right?

Comment: That's correct, yes.